# AWS Device farm seems to be ignoring TestNG annotations

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, testng, aws-device-farm

I have successfully uploaded and run my tests on AWS device farm.  Locally, I'm using fun things like @Test(enabled = false, dependsOnGroups = "Login") to mark which tests to run at the time, and what order they should execute.  Locally, this all works fine and dandy as expected.  The problem happens after I upload the zip of the maven build to device farm and perform a test run.

Looking at the logs from device farm, it doesn't care if "enabled" is set to true or false, it'l run things regardless.  It also ignores the "group=" and "dependsOnGroups" annotations.  This is super important, since all other tests will fail if I'm not logged in first.  Worse, the subsequent failing tests will not be skipped, so AWS is happily charging me more money off of this.

I tried using @Test(priority=blah), but it's ignoring that too.  The only thing it seems to be respecting are things like @BeforeSuite and @AfterSuite.

Anyone run into this or have any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am an engineer working on AWS Device Farm.

**1) "enabled" annotation flag**

I just verified that you are correct about our TestNG parser ignoring the "enabled" flag on annotations and always including the test, even if it is disabled. At first glance, this appears to be a simple issue with a straight forward fix. Assuming best case scenario, we will try and have it fixed and live in production as soon as we can.

**2) "dependsOnGroups" annotation field**

The answer to this one is a bit more complex. As of today, AWS Device Farm does not support the **dependsOnGroups** or **dependsOnMethods** annotation fields.

There are a few reasons for this, with the main reason being that AWS Device Farm executes each `@Test` method individually, each one using a fresh instance of the Appium server. There are pros/cons to this approach that I won't delve into here, but I will say that it does have benefits on both a technical and feature level. When executing individual methods with the `TestNG` runner, it will only load the context of an individual method, and not all tests/suites/groups of the specified dependencies found within the `.jar` file. Additionally, since each one of these test methods is executed in a different `Java` process each time, the `TestNG` runner does not maintain any "state" in memory. This means that it does not know that it has already executed a test previously (in a different process) so it will attempt to run it again.

**3) Executing "groups" of tests**

We currently do not expose `groups/excludegroups` to the user to allow them to pick specific collections of tests to execute or skip. However, this should be possible by configuring your `<groups>` entries in a `testng.xml` file placed in the root of your `*-tests.jar` file that is uploaded in your test package archive. In this case, our parser should only "discover" tests defined within those groups and not all `@Test` annotated methods. I have not tried this specific case however, so your YMMV.

---

Hope that helps! If you have any additional questions or have a specific run/test package you'd like us to look at, feel free to reach out or paste a URL to a previously executed run.

Comment: Thanks for responding.  I think it would be helpful to future devs if the lack of annotation support was noted on the relevant amazon TestNG page.  Doing so would save some people from having to figure that out the hard way.

Comment: Thank you, I spent way to long trying to figure out errors caused by lack of dependency support you describe in #2. I agree this would be a good thing to add to the Device Farm documentation.

Comment: Our team ran into the exact same problem when trying to specify an order of execution. We tried specifying it both in the testng.xml file and as a priority attribute of the Test annotation @Test(priority=n). Both failed. Now the question we're struggling to answer @ahawker is whether Device Farm will completely ignore the Testng.xml file or just certain aspects of it. So far it looks like it ignores it completely. Can you please comment on this?

Comment: Two years later to this question... Is there any update to this issue? Will this anotations ever be supported?

Answer (score -2):

I added testng.xml in the root of *-tests.jar and checked.

But device farm is not running the tests listed in testng.xml. It's still running all the classes with @Test annotation

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.