# AWS - Junit Tests Not Running - Only Setup and Teardown Suites

Tags: maven, amazon-web-services, junit, appium, appium-ios

In AWS I have created a project and run .jar in java appium ios testing.

The problem is, it execute setup and teardown methods only and does not execute @Test method.

I have created .jar file as instructed. But only setup and teardown is executed. Can you please have a look?

This is my junit script..
https://gist.github.com/Sandarekha/4753fb85102c3f8b6781bcd9b0b1d5ed

This is POM.xml 
https://gist.github.com/Sandarekha/fc11f4444b3c7c7150e25cf7252a1860

In the provided video, App has not even launched.

1. Why my tests annotation is being ignored?
2. Why the app is not launched? I have used 
      driver.launchApp(); 
   but not respond?

Comment: Maybe something from answer here will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34599482/aws-device-farm-seems-to-be-ignoring-testng-annotations

Comment: Rename `DDMainview`  to `DDMainviewTest` and try again