# Unable to access properties file information in Amazon aws device farm

Tags: java, android, maven, appium, aws-device-farm

I've an automation script where in I wanted to executed the same on AWS device farm

Framework implemented in Maven
and all the respective plugins are mentioned in pom.xml as suggested by AWS
I'm able to run the scripts on my local standalone machine
Tech used Appium + Java + TestNG + Android
Successfully uploaded ZIP and apk into AWS

Converted into Zip as shown,

[image]

and my Appium-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-tests contains following files

[image]

My framework uses these properties files to pass values to the scripts, so when I trigger the execution it is failing to invoke the properties files

AWS device farm says,
"Tests skipped due to test package parsing error"

Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

I can't add a comment yet but I wanted to ask for the message returned in the parse result file.

It also may be failing because of some of the configurations set in the testng.xml

[Testng XML not accepted by AWS Device Farm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45458837/testng-xml-not-accepted-by-aws-device-farm/45526591#45526591)

It doesn't appear that all tags in the testng.xml are supported yet in Device Farm.

An example of a valid project using testng can be found at the awslabs github page:

https://github.com/awslabs/aws-device-farm-appium-tests-for-sample-app

Answer (score 0):

```
ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
                Properties configs = new Properties();

                BufferedReader metadataReader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(loader.getResourceAsStream(config.property)));
                sUserConfigs.load(new StringReader(IOUtils.toString(metadataReader).replace("\\", "/")));
```

you can invoke the property file by using above code.